# Search string exists in lists

Tags: tcl

How to search in each string exists in the lists.

```
set Listing [list AB ZS FR WQ GY GT DA PP YT PW]
set strings {ZS RW DA PW}

if { in each $strings no exists in the $listing} {
    lappend strNoExitst $get
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set Listing [list AB ZS FR WQ GY GT DA PP YT PW]
set strings {ZS RW DA PW}

set in_list {}
set not_in_list {}

foreach string $strings {
    if {$string in $Listing} {
        lappend in_list $string
    } else {
        lappend not_in_list $string
    }
}
```

Documentation:
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[in (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)